# Django admin, change current value of ForeignKey widget

Tags: django, django-admin

in my Django admin application I have one ForeignKey field with its relative widget in change page.

[image: ForeignKey widget with current value on top of select]

I wish to add a link to change view of current selected product instead of simple text of current product.

My models is composed of: WeddingList, Product and WeddingListProducts for m2m relationship...

In my admin.py the ProductAdmin class is an inline of WeddingListAdmin class.

This is my admin.py

```
class WeddingListProductsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WeddingListProducts
    form = WeddingListProductsAdminForm
    extra = 0

class WeddingListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (WeddingListProductsInline,)
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You want to be able to manually type in the FK value?

Comment: Hi, I want to substitute the current value name (on top of select widget) with an url that point to another view).

Comment: Can you post your `admin.py` code?

Comment: Maybe there's something for you here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

Comment: No, it's for the fieldset description text... I'm searching for override the ForeignKeyField (or SelectWidget) to edit current selected item. I change the image of the control in the main question.

Comment: You have to override the renderer of your widget (from django-selectable?). I guess it's a subclass of django.forms.TextInput widget that is modified by pure js. Your best chance is to have a look at that js file (jquery.dj.selectable.js I guess)

Comment: Yes, I'm using django-selectable, but in my question I've disabled its AutoCompleteSelectWidget... and I've left Django to decide default widget.... anyway, the problem is the same...

Comment: Maybe the solution is to override the template admin/edit_inline/tabular.html .... in it there is a property show_url .... but I don't know to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved my problem.
My solution is to override admin/edit_inline.html template with these code:

```
<td class="original">
        {% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}
            <p>
                {% if inline_admin_form.original %}
                    <a href="{% url 'admin:MyApp_product_change' inline_admin_form.original.product.id %}">
                        {{ inline_admin_form.original }}
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
```

and set the template attribute of my ModelAdmin class to corresponding url of new template.

admin.py

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = "admin/myapp/mymodel/edit_inline/tabular.html"
```

Please comment for any better solutions! Bye ;)

Comment: That's the way to do it! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model